# Yaml hierarchical data

Tags: yaml

I'd like to represent a hierarchy in yaml, and I'm not sure how. For example, I'd like to say something like this:

```
name: "user1"
programming-skill: 3
    java: 2
    python: 2
cooking-skill: 4
```

When I throw this at a yaml parser, I get an error along the lines of "mapping values not allowed here" on the line `java: 2` because I'm trying to assign `programming-skill` to both `3` and the list `{java: 2, python: 2}`.

What's the cleanest way to represent this hierarchical structure in yaml? Alternatively, is there a serialization format more suited than yaml to hierarchical structures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
name: "user1"
programming-skill: 
  - 3
  - java: 2
    python: 2
cooking-skill: 4
```

or if you prefer:

```
name: "user1"
programming-skill: 
  - 3
  - 
    java: 2
    python: 2
cooking-skill: 4
```

Answer (score 6):

```
name: "user1"
programming-skill:
        others:
            java: 2
            python: 2
        value: 3
cooking-skill: 4
```

[Test it here](http://instantyaml.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible to cleanly do this in yaml. You have to, as Andrey suggested, introduce new data (others/value) and work around it. I'm still not sure if there's a format that's better suited for this form of data, or if you just have to bite the bullet and introduce an extra level of hierarchy.